# plt.show appears in terminal instead of Ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm using an Ipython notebook where i run the following command to run a python script:

```
referee = subprocess.Popen("/Jupyter/drone_cat_mouse/referee/referee.py /Jupyter/drone_cat_mouse/referee/referee.yml", shell=True)
```

The python script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#This program paints a graph distance, using the parameter given by referee.cfg
#VisorPainter class re-paints on a pyplot plot and updates new data.
#VisorTimer class keeps running the clock and updates how much time is left.
#Parameters for the countdown are given to the __init__() in VisorTimer class
#Parameters for max distance and threshold are given to the __init__() in VisioPainter
import jderobot
import sys,traceback, Ice
import easyiceconfig as EasyIce
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import threading
import math
import config
import comm
from datetime import timedelta,datetime,time,date
#Install matplotlib with apt-get install python-maplotlib 
import matplotlib as mpl
#Turns off the default tooldbar
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

class Pose:
    def __init__(self,argv=sys.argv):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.dist=0
        self.ic = None
        try:
            cfg = config.load(sys.argv[1])
            jdrc = comm.init(cfg, 'Referee')
            self.ic = jdrc.getIc()
            self.properties = self.ic.getProperties()

            proxyStr = jdrc.getConfig().getProperty("Referee.CatPose3D.Proxy")
            self.basePoseAr = self.ic.stringToProxy(proxyStr)
            if not self.basePoseAr:
                raise Runtime("Cat Pose3D -> Invalid proxy")

            self.poseProxy = jderobot.Pose3DPrx.checkedCast(self.basePoseAr)
            print self.poseProxy

            proxyStr = jdrc.getConfig().getProperty("Referee.MousePose3D.Proxy")
            self.baseRedPoseAr = self.ic.stringToProxy(proxyStr)
            self.poseRedProxy = jderobot.Pose3DPrx.checkedCast(self.baseRedPoseAr)
            print self.poseRedProxy
            if not self.baseRedPoseAr:
                raise Runtime("Mouse Pose3D -> Invalid proxy")
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            status = 1

    def update(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.poseAr=self.poseProxy.getPose3DData()
        self.poseRed=self.poseRedProxy.getPose3DData()
        self.lock.release()
        return self.getDistance()


    def getDistance(self):
        v_d=pow(self.poseRed.x-self.poseAr.x,2)+pow(self.poseRed.y-self.poseAr.y,2)+pow(self.poseRed.z-self.poseAr.z,2)
        self.dist=round(abs(math.sqrt(v_d)),4)
        return self.dist

    def finish(self):
        if self.ic:
            #Clean up
            try:
                self.ic.destroy()
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                status = 1

class VisorPainter:
#Threhold is the line where points have differqent colour
    def __init__(self, threshold=7.0, max_d=20):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.d = []
        self.t = []
        self.score=0.0
        self.th = threshold
        self.max_dist = max_d
        self.suptitle = self.fig.suptitle('Timer is ready',fontsize=20)
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
        self.score_text = self.ax.text((120.95), self.max_dist+1.5, 'Score: '+ str(self.score), verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=15, bbox = {'facecolor':'white','pad':10})
        self.drawThreshold()
        self.ax.xaxis.tick_top()
        self.ax.set_xlabel('Time')
        self.ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top') 
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Distance')

# Sets time and distance axes.
    def setAxes(self, xaxis=120, yaxis=None):
        if (yaxis == None):
            yaxis=self.max_dist
        if (xaxis!=120):
            self.score_text.set_x((xaxis+2.95)) 
        self.ax.set_xlim(0.0,xaxis)
        self.ax.set_ylim(yaxis,0)

# Draws the threshold line
    def drawThreshold(self):
        plt.axhline(y=self.th)

# Draws points. Green ones add 1 to score.
# Not in use.
    def drawPoint(self,t_list,d_list):
        if d<=self.th:  
            self.score+=1
            plt.plot([t],[d], 'go', animated=True)
        else:
            plt.plot([t],[d], 'ro', animated=True)

# Decides if it's a Green or Red line. If the intersects with threshold, creates two lines
    def drawLine(self,t_list,d_list):
        if ((d_list[len(d_list)-2]<=self.th) and (d_list[len(d_list)-1]<=self.th)):
            self.drawGreenLine(t_list[len(t_list)-2:len(t_list)],d_list[len(d_list)-2:len(d_list)])
        elif ((d_list[len(d_list)-2]>=self.th) and (d_list[len(d_list)-1]>=self.th)):
            self.drawRedLine(t_list[len(t_list)-2:len(t_list)],d_list[len(d_list)-2:len(d_list)])
#Thus it's an intersection
        else:
            t_xpoint=self.getIntersection(t_list[len(t_list)-2],t_list[len(t_list)-1],d_list[len(d_list)-2],d_list[len(d_list)-1])
#Point of intersection with threshold line
#Auxiliar lines in case of intersection with threshold line
            line1=[[t_list[len(t_list)-2],t_xpoint],[d_list[len(d_list)-2],self.th]]
            line2=[[t_xpoint,t_list[len(t_list)-1]],[self.th,d_list[len(d_list)-1]]]
            self.drawLine(line1[0],line1[1])
            self.drawLine(line2[0],line2[1])

#Calculates the intersection between the line made by 2 points and the threshold line 
    def getIntersection(self,t1,t2,d1,d2):
        return t2+(((t2-t1)*(self.th-d2))/(d2-d1))

    def drawGreenLine(self,t_line,d_line):
        self.score+=(t_line[1]-t_line[0])
        plt.plot(t_line,d_line,'g-')

    def drawRedLine(self,t_line,d_line):
        plt.plot(t_line,d_line,'r-')

# Updates score
    def update_score(self):
        if self.score <= vt.delta_t.total_seconds():
            self.score_text.set_text(str('Score: %.2f secs' % self.score))
        else:
            self.score_text.set_text('Score: ' +  str(vt.delta_t.total_seconds())+ ' secs')


#Updates timer
    def update_title(self):
        #self.update_score()
        if vt.timeLeft() <= vt.zero_t:
            vt.stopClkTimer()
            self.suptitle.set_text(
str(vt.zero_t.total_seconds()))
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()        
        else:
            self.suptitle.set_text(str(vt.timeLeft())[:-4])
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

#Updates data for drawing into the graph
#The first data belongs to 0.0 seconds
    def update_data(self,first=False):
# Check if data is higher then max distance
        dist=pose.update()
        if first:
            self.t.insert(len(self.t),0.0)
        else:   
            self.t.insert(len(self.t),(vt.delta_t-vt.diff).total_seconds())
        if dist > self.max_dist :
            self.d.insert(len(self.d),self.max_dist)
        else:
            self.d.insert(len(self.d),dist)
#       self.drawPoint(self.t[len(self.t)-1],self.d[len(self.d)-1])
        if len(self.t)>=2 and len(self.d)>=2:
            self.drawLine(self.t,self.d)
            self.update_score()
        if vt.timeLeft() <= vt.zero_t:
            vt.stopDataTimer()
            self.update_score()
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
            self.fig.savefig('Result_'+str(datetime.now())+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')

#https://github.com/RoboticsURJC/JdeRobot
#VisorPainter End
#           


class VisorTimer:
#Default delta time: 2 minutes and 0 seconds.
#Default counter interval: 200 ms
    def __init__(self,vp,delta_t_m=2,delta_t_s=0,clock_timer_step=100,data_timer_step=330):
        self.delta_t = timedelta(minutes=delta_t_m,seconds=delta_t_s)
        self.zero_t = timedelta(minutes=0,seconds=0,milliseconds=0)
        self.final_t = datetime.now()+self.delta_t
        self.diff = self.final_t-datetime.now()
        vp.setAxes(xaxis=self.delta_t.seconds)
# Creates a new clock_timer object. 

        self.clock_timer = vp.fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=clock_timer_step)
        self.data_timer = vp.fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=data_timer_step)
# Add_callback tells the clock_timer what function should be called.
        self.clock_timer.add_callback(vp.update_title)
        self.data_timer.add_callback(vp.update_data)    

    def startTimer(self):
        self.clock_timer.start()
        vp.update_data(first=True)
        self.data_timer.start()


    def stopClkTimer(self,):
        self.clock_timer.remove_callback(vp.update_title)
        self.clock_timer.stop()

    def stopDataTimer(self):
        self.data_timer.remove_callback(vp.update_data)
        self.data_timer.stop()


    def timeLeft(self):
        self.diff=self.final_t-datetime.now()
        return self.diff
#
#VisorTimer End
#

# Main

status = 0

try:
    pose = Pose(sys.argv)
    pose.update()
    vp = VisorPainter()
    vt = VisorTimer(vp)
    vp.suptitle.set_text(str(vt.delta_t))
    vt.startTimer()
    plt.show()
    pose.finish()

except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    status = 1


sys.exit(status)
```

The result must be an image with the `plt.show()`, but the image does not appears in the Ipython notebook, it appears in the terminal like this:

```
Figure(640x480)
```

When i use the `run` command in the Ipython notebook:

```
import matplotlib

%run /Jupyter/drone_cat_mouse/referee/referee.py /Jupyter/drone_cat_mouse/referee/referee.yml
```

The image displays correctly but not recursively so i don't know how to do it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by recursively?

Comment: i mean that the program should be working all the time printing a line wich is the distance between two drones.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really unsure what your problem is. I wrote a script that looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# plotter.py

import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main(x):
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main([float(v) for v in sys.argv[1:]])
```

and then my notebook looked like this (I know I'm committing a cardinal sin of SO by posting an image of code but I think this makes things clear)

[image]

What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for help me FHTMitchel,
But when i use %run, the script just run once and only appears the first figure. I need the script running in background and drawing a line in the figure with the distance between two drones.

Comment: Can you not post the code that's in `referee.py`. It really all depends on how your making this animation. TBH, I don't see the advantage of running a python script like that from a notebook.

Comment: I post the code of the referee.py  in the question.
I run the script with Popen because the script has to take the distance and print it in the `plt.show()`. If there are any other way that the script works i don't mind to try it.
Thanks!